# how to sharp an image thumbnail in java?

Tags: java, density-independent-pixel

I have created a thumbnail image in java using imgscalr library and thumbnail created with good quality but i want to sharpen that thumbnail.

so please help me to sharpen thumbnail image.

Answer (score 0):

See These links. Maybe you will get to know how to start

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/image/sharpening-a-buffered-image/

http://asserttrue.blogspot.in/2010/01/sharpening-image-using.html#